# Dirac measures closed in Radon measures?

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, weak-convergence

Let $M(X)$ be the space of Radon probability measures on a compact space $X$. Consider the subset $Y:= \{\delta_x: x \in X\}$ of point-measures (Dirac measures), explicitely defined by
$$\delta_x(A) = \begin{cases}1 & x \in A \\ 0 & x \notin A\end{cases}.$$

The space $M(X)$ can be identified with the state space of $C(X)$: $M(X) \cong S(C(X))$ where the isomorphism is given by
$$\mu \mapsto (f \mapsto \int_X fd \mu).$$
Since $S(C(X))\subseteq C(X)^*$, the space $M(X)$ obtains a weak$^*$-topology through this identification. My question is: Is the set $Y$ closed in $M(X)$ with respect to the weak$^*$-topology?

Concretely, let $\{x_\alpha\}$ be a net in $X$ and suppose that
$$\delta_{x_\alpha}\to \mu$$
in the weak$^*$-topology, i.e.
$$\lim_\alpha f(x_\alpha) = \int_X fd \mu$$
for all $f \in C(X)$. Can we conclude that $\mu = \delta_x$ for some $x \in X$?

My idea: I want to show that maybe somehow $\{x_\alpha\}$ converges to $x\in X$ and then this $x$ might be a candidate.

Other observation, but not particularly useful here: By the Hahn-Banach theorem, the convex hull of $Y$ is weak$^*$-dense in $M(X)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By compactness there is a subnet which converges to some point $x$ and we have $f(x)=\int fd\mu$ for all $f \in C(X)$. By Riesz Representation Theorem $\int f d\mu_1=\int fd\mu_2$ for all $f \in C(X)$ implies that $\mu_1=\mu_2$ so we must have $\mu =\delta_x$.